# Synchronizing style changes during javascript function progress

Tags: javascript, css, synchronization

I am trying to indicate function progression while a long-running function causes the page to appear unresponsive. My first attempt was to simply begin and end my function with stylesheet commands like so:

```
function myFunc() {
  document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
  // main guts //
  document.body.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

This resulted in the "progress" cursor seemingly not having a chance to manifest before the time-consuming "guts" take over, ending with the cursor back at default. This appears to me to be an issue of timing or synchronization because

```
function myFunc() {
  document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
  if(document.body.style.cursor == "progress") {
    // main guts //
  }
  document.body.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

performs just like my first attempt, from which I infer that javascript recognizes the stylesheet change, but does not have time to show it before diving into the "guts." Separating the stylesheet changes from the "guts" and using setTimeout, like so:

```
function myFunc() {
  document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
  setTimeout(guts, 100);  // tried up to 5000ms
  document.body.style.cursor = "default";
}
function guts() {
  // main guts //
}
```

performs no differently the previous attempts with the exception of the added time delay, as if the setTimeout was equally interrupting of manifesting the stylesheet changes.

Using an alert() after the change to "progress" remedies the problem, but is not appropriate for the intended usage. The cursor manifests its new style properly upon the alert and before diving into the "guts" with the following:

```
function myFunc() {
  document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
  alert("!"); // main guts //
  document.body.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

but I cannot be prompting the users in such a manner for such a reason. Another attempt was to use callback functions to sequence instructions, like so:

```
//// source
myFunc(guts);

//// target
function myFunc(cbFunc) {
  document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
  cbFunc();
  document.body.style.cursor = "default";
}
function guts() {
  // main guts //
}
```

but this results in the same performance as the non-alert cases. I have also tried using background colors instead of cursor styles (in case this issue was particular to cursors) to no avail.

Can someone identify my misunderstanding(s) with this kind of flow-control in javascript?

-UPDATES-

Also to no avail:

```
function myFunc() {
  document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
  document.body.style.cursor = guts();
}
function guts() {
  // main guts //
  return "default";
}
```

Thank you dandavis for the following solution:

```
function myFunc() {
  document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
  setTimeout(guts, 50);  // needs at least 10ms in my observations
}
function guts() {
  // main guts //
  document.body.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

Comment: You understand that if the "guts" is asynchronous logic, the next statement that resets the cursor will execute before it finishes, right?

Comment: Browsers put off updating the page for as long as they can. *Usually* synchronous JavaScript code doesn't take that much time (milliseconds) so it's smart for the browser to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are close with the second one. You just have to wait for the "guts" to finish cranking before you re-apply the original style.  The bottom of a callback or timeout is the natural place to do that for the perfect amount of time:

```
function myFunc() {
  document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
  setTimeout(guts, 1);

}

function guts() {
  // main guts //
  document.body.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

changing to 1ms should still allow the style to "percolate" without a noticeable delay.

Comment: This does not appear to function any differently than my previous attempts, implemented with either setTimeout or callback functions. The "progress" cursor doesn't appear with the return to "default" being moved to the bottom of the "guts."

Comment: Contrary to my recent response, this does work if given enough time -  I needed more than a several milliseconds to observe it working. Currently using 50ms which is fast enough to not be noticed, testing fails for me using 10ms or less.